# react js Button hide HTML title default tooltip for React JS using CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I got many buttons that I need  to disable or hide the `HTML` default tooltip which results from the title attribute in the `<Button title='test'></Button>`

I read several posts here that advise using the `CSS` pointer-events which disables the the hover tooltip but  also the button click. `<Button title='test' style={{pointer-events: none}}></Button>`

I could not find any posts here on remove the title attribute from the button in React component like `removeAttr('title')` so I move on to

trying to hide the HTML Tooltip content box and text with styling the tooltip border, text, and background to white with something like this

```
const buttonStyle = {
  hover: {
    color: '#fff", backgroundColor: '#fff' 
  }
  //'&:hover':{
  //  color: '#fff", backgroundColor: '#fff' 
  //}
}
```

tried both hover: and '&:hover' : {} with white background to hide the html tooltip, but the styling is not taking effect.

```
<Button title='test' style={buttonStyle}></Button>
```

So far no luck and removing the title attribute from button control is not an option.

Comment: Is this material UI?

Comment: react-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I found this simple solution if you want to hide the button title tooltip in react.

<button className="button" title="" {...props}>buttonTitle